# $A.getCallback() [TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am new to building lightning component. I have create a sample app for accounts list to display. But when the page loads i get a failed call back error pop as below:

[image]

**App**:

```
<aura:application >
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDSv1/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css" />
<div class="slds">
    <div class="slds-page-header">
      <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate">
          <p class="slds-text-heading--label">Account</p>
          <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-type-focus slds-no-space">
              <h1 class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-truncate" title="My Accounts">My Accounts</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-p-top--large">
        <c:accountList />
    </div>
</div>
</aura:application>
```

**Controller**:

```
    public with sharing class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccount() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
    }
}
```

**AcountList component:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="AccountController">

    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <!-- Display account records -->
    <div class="container slds-p-top--medium">
        <div id="list" class="row">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc">
                <p>{!acc.Name}
                </p>
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>
    </div> 
</aura:component>
```

**AccountList Controller JS:**

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
   helper.getAllAccounts(component);


}

})
```

**AccountList Helper:**

```
    ({
    getAllAccounts: function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.getAccount");
        alert('Action--'+action);
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            alert('Response---'+response.getState());
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.accounts", response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if(response.getState() == "ERROR"){
                $A.log("callback error", response.getError());
            }
        });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
})
```

Comment: Are you on winter 17 org or summer ? Little bit info on how you are testing this should help

Comment: Also try taking all your code inside component itself and keep the aura:app with only c:component

Comment: This is weird, I tried your code in my dev org and it works good. However you have placed one extra comma after getAllAccounts method but that is not causing any problem.

Comment: Hi Mohit, I am using the summer 16 org and for testing i am using the normal salesforce apex debug console and javascript alert and console logs. Have moved the app code to component,but still i get the error.

Comment: Just to get it narrower can you try in a different org ? Is it sandbox ?

Comment: yes its a free developers org summer 16.

Comment: Do you have my domain enabled ? Probably spin a new winter 17 pre release org and test the code

Comment: yes its enabled. Will try in other org and test it.

Comment: Tried in winter 17 org, getting the same error again. Have i missed to enable any setting in the setup?

Comment: The only place in the Lightning framework (Aura) where we use WeakMap is in Locker Service. I strongly suspect this is an issue with the proxy caching in LS combined with the attribute of type Account[] and do not think the issue is in your code. Please deactivate LS under Setup | Critical Updates (not the one for Communities) and let us know if the error goes away. If you do not see the deactivate row please let me know the orgid for the org you are testing in and I will add the ability to toggle LS (all orgs will have this very soon btw)..

Comment: @Gaurav I've opened bug W-3382833 to track this if you need to reference it in a case with Salesforce support. The LS team has it in their active queue now.