# $A.callback Failed, Action Failed: $controller$doinit [Invalid value used as weak map key]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, locker-service

I am facing a similar issue like what is explained in this link :-[$A.getCallback() [TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142150/a-getcallback-typeerror-invalid-value-used-as-weak-map-key)

We can avoid this situation by deactivating the Locker Services, but this isn't the solution, because after 14 jun 2017, it will be automatically activated everywhere, then we will have the same situation to face.

Kindly help me with this issue, how we can overcome it.

Comment: The last item in the comment thread of the question you linked to says "@Gaurav I've opened bug W-3382833 to track this if you need to reference it in a case with Salesforce support. The LS team has it in their active queue now. – Doug Chasman Sep 28 '16 at 14:19". As that was months ago I suggest you create a case quoting that bug number if you believe your problem is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Keith , I am raising a case with salesforce, but just posted the question here, if anyone might come up with a solution of the same.

Comment: Fair enough. Seems pretty nasty.

Comment: Any specifics on exactly what Javascript you're executing when the error occurs or any other debug info would be helpful to try to figure out what's going on.